# jFreeChart: DateAxis to behave like a CategoryAxis. Only discrete datevalues to be printed

Tags: jfreechart

I have a TimeSeries Chart with a XYdataset which has the milliseconds of each dates.
Now I want to have a chart that only displays each date one time on the axis, no matter what the range of dates is. I already got it so far, that only the date is printed, not the time (via setNumberFormatOverride() method).
What I have now, is this:
[alt text http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1144075/Bildschirmfoto%202010-08-05%20um%2016.51.39.JPG](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1144075/Bildschirmfoto%202010-08-05%20um%2016.51.39.JPG)

What I want, is this:
[alt text http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1144075/Bildschirmfoto%202010-08-05%20um%2016.54.54.JPG](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1144075/Bildschirmfoto%202010-08-05%20um%2016.54.54.JPG)

This is a snippet of my code. also, the setLabelAngle() method don't work?!

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(...);
XYPlot xyplot = (XYPlot)chart.getPlot();
DateAxis dateaxis = (DateAxis) xyplot.getDomainAxis();
dateaxis.setLabelAngle(Math.PI / 6.0);`
numberaxis.setNumberFormatOverride((DecimalFormat)DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [`TickUnit`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/TickUnit.html) to any convenient [`DateTickUnitType`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/DateTickUnitType.html). I use `DAY` in this example and `MMM` to verify the `Locale`:

```
axis.setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.DAY, 1,
    new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MMM.yy", Locale.GERMAN)));
```

As you are a returning customer, I'll address the second question, too: [`setLabelAngle()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/Axis.html#setLabelAngle%28double%29) works perfectly well, but it changes the axis label in the chart legend. Using [`setVerticalTickLabels()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/ValueAxis.html#setVerticalTickLabels%28boolean%29) is an alternative for the tick labels themselves:

```
axis.setVerticalTickLabels(true);
```

Comment: axis.setVerticalTickLabels(true) displays the labels vertically. If you want to change the angle of the tick labels at 45 degrees, let's say, then setLabelAngle() will be of no use for DateAxis.