# Display non Gregorian dates in X-Axis of a JFreeChart TimeSeries

Tags: java, date, jfreechart, time-series

Assuming by having A Jalali Calendar Class, Is it Possible to use JFreeChart's TimeSeries Chart with Jalali dates?
If yes, How?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Jalali does not appear among the [Supported Locales](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/locales-137662.html). If you can find an implementation, you can use the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3421194/230513).