# JFreeCharts TimeSeriesChart set domain interval

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, jfreechart, timeserieschart

How to set time interval for Domain axis in TimeSeriesChart? 
Now i have domain axis with labels which looks something like: 22.00 23.00, 00.00, 1.00, 2.00, etc.

How can I set them like: 11 feb, 12 feb etc. 
I should have posibility to see all hourse  only if I zoom  chart.

Edit: Now I solve it with the help of `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
DateAxis dateAxis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
DateFormatSymbols dfs = DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(); // default locale
dateAxis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-HH:mm", dfs));
```

Chart displayed :

[image]

Edit: The question is still open: Is it possible to set something like grouping by day for domain axis?

Edit: More information:)
I try to get some data for last week period, but if data in database only for 1 or 2 days, chart will look like this:
[image]

as you can see timline on domain axis store information from 00.00(actualy start time is 23.xx) till 10.00, and it's no good, because user should see day which data belongs. In this case I create TimeSeries and fill it like :

```
TimeSeries ts=new TimeSeries(name);
ts.addOrUpdate(new Hour(date), value);
```

If I fill ts like

```
ts.addOrUpdate(new Day(date), value);
```

then chart didn't show any data

[image]

Quistion is how to make chart group data (maybe with the help  of zoom ) by days, like in the following chart?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you add any [`RegularTimePeriod`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/RegularTimePeriod.html) to a [`TimeSeries`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/TimeSeries.html), the corresponding axis will use the inferred period as a guide to formatting. A  related example that uses `Day` may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6210074/230513).

Addendum: See also this related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3421194/230513) concerning `DateTickUnit`.

Comment: Thank you for response. I have already try it , but in this case some charts which store info for hours was empty. for example I have 0 data item at 0.00, 1 at 7.00 and 0 again at 2.00  data added with regular time period Hour, in this case chart displayed like triangle, and this is ok... but when i Use Day RegularTimePeriod -chart empty, and domain axis contains dates 23:59:59:999  and 00:00:00:000

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: Yes I have, in this case hours is missing even if I zoom in chart. I suppose the best way is to set date format. Anyway seems like customer approve it :). But I  left question unsolved